# Efficient way to perform radial average of matrix elements without using shared memory

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpuimage, gpu, jcuda

I am trying to implement radial average of matrix element in CUDA, where I have to find and print average of all neighbouring elements (including itself) of every matrix element. Following is what I ended up with(for radius = 1):

```
__global__ void matrix_avg(float *ad,float *bd)
{
    float t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, avg;
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int k = (i*N)+(j);

    if(i==0)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k+1]+ad[k+N]+ad[k+N+1]+ad[k])/4;
            }
            else if(j==N-1)
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k-1]+ad[k+N]+ad[k+N-1]+ad[k])/4;
            }
            else
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k-1]+ad[k+1]+ad[k+N-1]+ad[k+N]+ad[k+N+1]+ad[k])/6;
            }
        }
        else if(i==N-1)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k+1]+ad[k-N]+ad[k-N+1]+ad[k])/4;
            }
            else if(j==N-1)
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k-1]+ad[k-N]+ad[k-N-1]+ad[k])/4;
            }
            else
            {
                bd[k]=(ad[k-1]+ad[k+1]+ad[k-N-1]+ad[k-N]+ad[k-N+1]+ad[k])/6;
            }
        }
        else if(j==0)
        {
            bd[k]=(ad[k-N]+ad[k-N+1]+ad[k+1]+ad[k+N]+ad[k+N+1]+ad[k])/6;
        }
        else if(j==N-1)
        {
            bd[k]=(ad[k-N-1]+ad[k-N]+ad[k-1]+ad[k+N-1]+ad[k+N]+ad[k])/6;
        }
        else
        {
            t1=ad[k-N-1];
            t2=ad[k-N];
            t3=ad[k-N+1];
            t4=ad[k-1];
            t5=ad[k+1];
            t6=ad[k+N-1];
            t7=ad[k+N];
            t8=ad[k+N+1];
            t9=ad[k];
            avg=(t1+t2+t3+t4+t5+t6+t7+t8+t9)/9;
            bd[k]=avg;
        }
}
```

My above code checks for the conditions of top row, bottom row, right most and left most column elements, for which it has to calculate average of 6 elements. Ans also for 4 corner elements for which it has to calculate average of 4 elements. For remaining inner elements it has to calculate average of 9 elements. 
Above code is just a simple conversion C to CUDA program. I am looking for most efficient way without using shared memory to write the program., for any given radius.
Any algorithm, pseudo code or suggestion will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the thing is I have to write conditions for those 9 types of elements(4 corners+ 4 side border elements+ inner elements). What is the efficient way to to bring all them under one condition for variable radius option? Is zero padding (extra rows and columns padding as per the radius size)is an efficient way to do it?

Comment: What is the reason not to use shared memory?

Comment: @MichalHosala: Well, First I wanted to check for the efficient way to implement it over my code above! This is surely an example of embarrassingly parallel problem, and shared memory will be definitely very useful. But I wanted to go for the basic implementation first, and then for shared memory.

Comment: You may be interested in [Box Filter with NPP demo](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#box-filter-with-npp).

Comment: @MichalHosala : How about without using any existing library?

Comment: An aside: I think the *general* term for what you are trying to achieve is a *convolution*. The averaging that you are talking about seems to be a *convolution with a gaussian kernel*. ("Kernel" here does not refer to a CUDA kernel)

Comment: @Marco13 :Oh.. I am not aware of image processing methods and techniques. I will surely look into Gaussian filter! Thanks.

Comment: And don't forget that your filter is a separable one (meaning, instead of 2D filter you can use 2 1D filters). This will speed up your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I implemented radial average of matrix elements without using shared memory:

```
__global__ void matrix_avg(float *ad,float *bd, int radius, int N)
{
    int counter =0,i,j;
    float sum=0.0;

    int globalRow = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int globalCol = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for(i=-radius;i<=radius;i++)
    {
        for(j=-radius;j<=radius;j++)
        {
            if(((globalRow+i)<0) || ((globalCol+j)<0) || ((globalRow+i)>=N) || ((globalCol+j)>=N))
            {
                sum = sum + 0;
            }
            else
            {
                sum = sum + ad[(globalRow+i)*N+(globalCol+j)];
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    bd[globalRow*N+globalCol]=sum/counter;
}
```

ad - Input matrix.

bd - Output matrix

N - Matrix dimension. (I kept it as square matrix for now)

radius - radius to perform range for average calculation

Comment: Average calculation for boundary elements wasn't that hard as I thought. Now I can go for optimized shared memory implementation for the same.

Comment: Also, what I did in my C code (in question part) is an absolute mess. :-|